# Set component focus with RTTI

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Is it possible to reach any control Focus property through Rtti? What I want is to set its value to True if the control is Empty. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
procedure SetFirstEmptyCtrlFocused;

  function HasTextProp(aControl: TControl): Boolean;
  var
    Ctx: TRttiContext;
    Prop: TRttiProperty;
  begin
    Prop := lCtx.GetType(aControl.ClassType).GetProperty('Text');
    Result := (Prop <> nil) and (Prop.Visibility in [mvPublic, mvPublished]) 
      and (Prop.GetValue(aControl).ToString = '');
  end;

var
  ObjList: TObjectList<TControl>;
  objIdx: Integer;
  Ctrl: TControl;

begin
  ObjList := TObjectList<TControl>.Create;
  ObjList.Add(cxTextEdit1);
  ObjList.Add(cxDateEdit1);
  ObjList.Add(cxTextEdit2);

  for objIdx := 0 to lObjList.Count -1 do
  begin
    Ctrl := lObjList.Items[objIdx];

    if HasTextProp(lCtrl) then
    begin
      SetCtrlFocused //...??
      Break;
    end;
  end;   
end;
```

Comment: Is this inside a specific form?

Comment: Yes It is, but Good question... what if it is on a datamodule and the form connected through an interface which implements the controls.

Comment: What delphi version do you use?

Comment: delphi 10.1 - Berlin

Comment: You tagged the question XE. That was the version that followed 2010 and preceeded XE2. Very many of your questions are wrongly tagged. I fixed this one.

Comment: With _Focus_ do you mean _TWinControl.Focused_? Not every _TControl_ can receive the focus, only _TWinControl_ can. You can set the focus of a _TWinControl_ with _SetFocus_.

Comment: Yeah, but to do that I need the object name (for example cxTextEdit1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every *TControl* can receive the focus, only *TWinControl* can. So instead of *TControl* use *TWinControl* and use its method *SetFocus*:

```
procedure SetFirstEmptyWinCtrlFocused;

  function HasTextProp(aControl: TWinControl): Boolean;
  var
    Ctx: TRttiContext;
    Prop: TRttiProperty;
  begin
    Prop := Ctx.GetType(aControl.ClassType).GetProperty('Text');
    Result := (Prop <> nil) and (Prop.Visibility in [mvPublic, mvPublished]) 
      and (Prop.GetValue(aControl).ToString = '');
  end;

var
  ObjList: TObjectList<TWinControl>;
  objIdx: Integer;
  Ctrl: TWinControl;

begin
  ObjList := TObjectList<TWinControl>.Create;
  ObjList.Add(cxTextEdit1);
  ObjList.Add(cxDateEdit1);
  ObjList.Add(cxTextEdit2);

  for objIdx := 0 to lObjList.Count -1 do
  begin
    Ctrl := lObjList.Items[objIdx];

    if HasTextProp(Ctrl) then
    begin
      Ctrl.SetFocus;
      Break;
    end;
  end;   
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Uwe!

Comment: Keep in mind that `SetFocus` raises an exception when `CanFocus` returns false (when the control is disabled or invisible) - this should be checked first.